# Need to use fstream to take input from ".in" files and store different data types

Tags: c++, string, io, fstream

Basically what I'm aiming for is to take input from a "`new.in`" file that look something like:

```
5 1 2 1
3 onion pepper olive
3 mushroom tomato basil
3 chicken mushroom pepper
3 tomato mushroom basil
2 chicken basil
```

I want to take the 4 numbers in the 1st line and store them in 4 different variables.

**And then I want to basically define one struct for the lines that follows (line 2 onwards) that stores the 1st number in an `int` and the rest of the words using `blank space` as a delimiter in a string vector or smth(I'm open to suggestions on these).**

*So for example, if you look at line 2, I want to take 3 and store it in my stuct.num and the following 3 ingredients in a vector (re-iterating that I'm open to suggestions for this. Could take input in a set as well, as I'm not that sure about this).*

What I've implemented as of now is just for the 1st line of the input (i.e. the 1st 4 digits on line 1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
    
        ifstream myfile("new.in");
        int a, b, c, d;
        myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        int m = a;
        int t2 = b;
        int t3 = c;
        int t4 = d;
    }
```

UPDATE : Sp I've gotten to the point where I'm able to print the numbers and strings from line 2 onwards from the .in files. Still need to know how I can store each of those lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

fstream& GotoLine(fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    file.seekg(ios::beg);
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

struct ing{
    int num;
    vector<string> ingredients;
};
    
int main(){

    ifstream myfile("new.in");
    int a, b, c, d;
    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    int m = a;
    int t2 = b;
    int t3 = c;
    int t4 = d;

    cout << m << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << " " << t4 << endl;

    for(int i = 2; i<2+m; i++){
        fstream file("new.in");

        GotoLine(file, i);

        string line2a;
        string line2b;
        string line2new;
        file >> line2a;
        getline(file, line2b);
        line2b.erase(line2b.begin());

        cout << line2a << endl;
        cout << line2b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm going to be using, it is a little complex but this is what I've been able to come up with.   *sigh*

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

fstream& GotoLine(fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    file.seekg(ios::beg);
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

struct ing{
    vector<string> num;
    vector<string> ingredients;
};

int main(){

    ifstream myfile("new.in");
    int a, b, c, d;
    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    int m = a;
    int t2 = b;
    int t3 = c;
    int t4 = d;

    cout << m << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << " " << t4 << endl;

    ing ING;
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i<2+m; i++){
        fstream file("new.in");

        GotoLine(file, i);

        string line2a;
        string line2b;

        file >> line2a;//1st num of each line starting from line 2
        ING.num.push_back(line2a);

        getline(file, line2b);
        line2b.erase(line2b.begin());

        ING.ingredients.push_back(line2b);

        cout << ING.num[j] << " ";
        cout << ING.ingredients[j] << endl;
        j++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```